# Cleaner way to pass ref in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuejs3

I'm facing a difficulty trying to get Popper.js to work "cleanly". I essentially have beat it into submission by adding nextTick everywhere, but its very fragile as its already broken twice two separate times I updated vue.

I want to convert it to the proper way but the problem is I have several limitations.

Here is how I use it:

```
<template>
  <div class="inline-flex">
    <div ref="tooltip">
      <base-svg @mouseover="open = true" @mouseleave="open = false" name="info" />
    </div>

    <transition @enter="enter" @leave="leave" :css="false">
      <base-popper :open="open" :reference="$refs.tooltip" :modifier-offset="[0, 14]" :modifier-gpu="false">
        <div class="w-64 bg-white shadow-lg border border-gray-400 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">
          <div class="p-2">
            <slot />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div data-popper-arrow><div class="bg-white border-r border-b border-gray-400"></div></div>
      </base-popper>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is how I handle it inside popper

```
  watch: {
    reference() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.init();
      });
    },
    open() {
      if (!this.popper) return;
      // resolves issue where resizing browser when popper is closed causes position
      // to be wrong when opened again
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.popper.update();
      });
    },
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    // only destroy if it exists (if menu was never opened it never gets created)
    if (!this.popper) return;
    this.popper.destroy();
    this.popper = undefined;
  },
  methods: {
    init() {
      const popper = this.$el;

      const defaults = {
        placement: this.placement,
        strategy: this.strategy,
        modifiers: [
          { name: 'offset', options: { offset: this.modifierOffset } },
          { name: 'preventOverflow', options: { padding: 8 } },
          { name: 'computeStyles', options: { adaptive: true, gpuAcceleration: this.modifierGpu } },
        ],
      };
      this.popper = createPopper(this.reference, popper, {
        ...defaults,
        ...this.options,
      });
    },
  },
```

The easiest solution would be to simply use a slot, and pass the "button" that triggers the popup INTO popperjs, that way I don't really need a ref I could just access it that way, or at the very least it would be cleaner in the component (not trying to access parent ref)

The problem is the `<transition>` must wrap popper or it won't work, AND, the button itself must be outside the transition element, otherwise would be fading/hiding, and it obviously can't work like that. Given these restrictions the only way I see it working is if the button is outside `<transition>` or `<base-popper>` component

The transitions also need to be handled outside `base-popper` because I use velocity.js to animate it all sorts of ways, and it can't go inside the component.

How is the cleanest way to handle this without all the `nextTick`?

Comment: so, what is this `popper` you create using `createPopper`?

Comment: https://popper.js.org/

Comment: have you seen https://github.com/RobinCK/vue-popper

Comment: its junk, it doesnt support vue 3 and it doesnt even support popper 2. Overall it should be like 3 lines of code, so i dont need a library for that really. it is just frustrating trying to get the events correct :/

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you use it, and that was just the first result in google search - perhaps there is a better library, or perhaps see what another library is doing and compare it with your code - you say it should take 3 lines of code, you've posted more than 3 ... so

Comment: that was exagerating slightly, I just mean they have so much junk in that library when really all that is needed is to mount and destroy popper. they have a lot of extra logic doing things where i wouldnt do it like that. it also makes it very inflexible to animations. with that said i have looked at their source before and they also just clobber all the events... and on top of that it doesnt work for vue 3 so i cant even get a hint :/

Comment: fair enough, was a thought, didn't realise you'd already looked at that code

Comment: @Tallboy - Check out https://github.com/valgeirb/vue3-popper/blob/main/docs/guide/getting-started.md. It supports Vue 3 and Popper 2.

Comment: @Tallboy - As an update to my previous comment, check out https://floating-vue.starpad.dev/. It's a Vue 3 wrapper component that supports Floating UI, the successor to Popper.